# Using js and css with a wordpress plugin

Tags: scripting, wordpress

I am trying to use css and js in a wordpress plugin I developed. I looked into the codex and I know I have to use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to add js, and [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to add css with [plugins_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) to output the correct path, but I can't figure out how to do it. I have a file structure so that it's the plugin then plugin > css and plugin > js where css and js are folders that contain their respective files.

I tried doing:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script('js/tabpane.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('local/helptip.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('local/webfxapi.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('local/webfxlayout.js');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method'); // For use on the Front end (ie. Theme)
```

but it's not working at all, and the codex isn't of much more help. Could anyone let me know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

When adding files to backend plugins you need to do a few things within your code:

```
add_action('init', 'add_main_javascript');

function add_main_javascript(){
    $slug = "main";
    $file = "inc/js/$slug.js";
    include_js_files($file, $slug);
}

function include_js_files($file, $slug, $in_footer = NULL){
    if(!$file)
    $file = "inc/js/filename.js";
    $your_plugin_dir = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);
    $your_plugin_url = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);
    if(file_exists($your_plugin_dir.$file))
    // array('jquery') is the scope of the javascript
    // Set $in_footer to true if you need the js to be in the footer
    wp_enqueue_script("filename.js", $your_plugin_url.$file, array ( 'jquery' ), "", $in_footer);
}
```

Or you could use just the add_action('init', 'your_code_for_enqueue');